# Insufficient privileges compiling a package that updates another users tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an object in USER A that updates tables in USER B's schema.
When the package is run, it is run in Oracle using USER B's login.

USER A does not have privileges to update the tables in USER B's schema.
When I try to compile the package in USER A's schema, I get insufficient privileges error messages which stops it from compiling.

Is there a way to compile an object in USER A's schema, even though he doesn't have the privileges to update USER B's tables? If the package is run under the context of USER B, will the package correctly update the tables?

I don't want to put the package in USER B's schema.

Comment: Why don't you want to B to own the package?  That is the most sensible option.

Comment: User B is the schema for our application, and we do not want to create objects in this schema as any update to the schema will wipe our objects.

Comment: In most set-ups "the schema for our application" means that user owns *all* the relevant objects, including stored procs.  That arrangement has worked fine in every system I've known.  What is so special about your scenario?  What do you mean by "wipe our objects"?

Answer (score 2):

You can.  But it's probably not the best approach.  The package would need to be declared as an invoker's rights package.  And the `UPDATE` statement would need to use dynamic SQL.

Create the table in `B`

```
SQL> create table b.foo( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into b.foo values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Create the package in `A`.  Note that the package is declared `authid current_user` which means that it relies on the privileges of the invoking user rather than the defining user.  And since `A` cannot see the table, we use dynamic SQL so that the syntax checks are deferred to runtime

```
SQL> create package update_foo
  2    authid current_user
  3  as
  4    procedure set_val( p_new_val in number );
  5  end;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package body update_foo
  2  as
  3    procedure set_val( p_new_val in number )
  4    as
  5    begin
  6      execute immediate 'update b.foo set col1 = :new_val'
  7        using p_new_val;
  8    end;
  9* end;
SQL> /

Package body created.

SQL> grant execute on update_foo to b;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, `B` can execute the package and modify the data

```
SQL> exec a.update_foo.set_val( 2 );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1
----------
         2
```

In general, however, this isn't a particularly sensible approach.  In general, the whole point of having code in one schema and objects in another is to provide for a separation of duties and a separation of responsibilities.  If you have to be logged in as a user that can issue an `UPDATE` against the table anyway, having a package to do it doesn't add much security.  In this case, it's just adding complexity.

Comment: The need to use dynamic SQL illustrates the stupidity of the set up.  Either A should have rights on B's table or B should own the stored procedure.  The fact that neither pertains points to a failure of the human factor.  This is a technical fix for a political bug.